# Magento 2 Knockout Js Customer Name update issue after changing customer name

Tags: magento2, javascript, customer, customer-account, knockoutjs

I am having strange issue. In header, along with Welcome message i am showing Customer full name.

For that i am using knockout.js concept.

```
<?php if($block->customerLoggedIn()): ?>
<li class="customer-welcome">
    <span class="customer-name"
          role="link"
          tabindex="0"
          data-mage-init='{"dropdown":{}}'
          data-toggle="dropdown"
          data-trigger-keypress-button="true"
          data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
        <span data-bind="text: customer().fullname"></span>
        <button type="button"
                class="action switch"
                tabindex="-1"
                data-action="customer-menu-toggle">
            <span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Change')) ?></span>
        </button>
    </span>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "customer": {
                        "component": "Magento_Customer/js/model/customer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

using above code displaying customer full name in header when customer logged in.  For Ex:   welcome Peter Parkar

When we change the customer name from account information section like below screenshot  it doesn't update the customer name in header.  If we logut and re-login then only it shows customer's updated name in header.

[image]

If we update the customer name it doesn't immediately reflect customer name in header.

What could be the issue?  How can i resolve it?  is there any way knockout.js can check for the updated details?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi any resolution to this issue?